# Refreshing data in EntityFramework

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, structuremap, unit-of-work

I have written a WPF application, but I have a problem in Refreshing data which are fetched from SQL Server database.

I am using StructureMap to inject dependencies and also manage the Lifecycle of DBContext. This is my Configuration of StructureMap:

```
ObjectFactory.Container.Configure(cfg =>
{
   cfg.For<IUnitOfWork>()
      .LifecycleIs(new ThreadLocalStorageLifecycle())
      .Use<DBContext>();
});
```

But when I edit a record from another instance of application or from SQL Server directly, the client which had fetched the record before, couldn't refresh itself and just show the unmodified data.

I used **.LifecycleIs(new ThreadLocalStorageLifecycle())** to have a different Context on each Thread to clear the cache of EntityFramework but it doesn't work.

This is my Service class:

```
public class DraftService : IDraftService
{
    IUnitOfWork _uow;
    IDbSet<Models.Draft> _draft;

    public DraftService(IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        _uow = uow;
        _draft = _uow.Set<Models.Draft>();
    }

    public Models.Draft GetByID(long id)
    {
       return _draft.Find(id);
    }
}
```

and I am using the Service as follows:

```
public class Draft
{
    private IUnitOfWork _uow;
    private IDraftService _draftService;

    public Draft(IUnitOfWork uow, IDraftService draftService)
    {
        _uow = uow;
        _draftService = draftService;
    }

    public async Task<Models.Draft> GetByID(long id)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => _draftService.GetByID(id));
    }
}
```

What is wrong? Why it doesn't Refresh the data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could Wrap the unit of work in a factory and use it in a using(var uow = uowfactory.instance()) { //do some stuff here //save at the end to persist data.} that way you won't have the cache problem. or the bugs that might happen from using the same context for all the application logic.

Comment: You are right Rugdr. The problem is how to dispose the context? Shouldn't ".LifecycleIs(new ThreadLocalStorageLifecycle())" works and renew the context on each Thread?

Comment: Depends if the application restart or not i guess it doesn't in that case you should consider using "AlwaysUnique" as lifetime. That way you just need to call Container.GetInstance<IUnitOfWork>() to get your new/not-cached, unique context to the database. Should work across thread too. (but you'll need to get a new instance of your service each time you want it to refresh)

Answer (score 1):

Edit: After a moment of lucidity here's what's happening.

replace : `return _draft.Find(id); // Find use the Cache if it can.`
By : `return _draft.SingleOrDefault(x => x.id == id) // SingleOrDefault should Fetch from the database each time.`

---

My comment is not clear enough let's take a look at this:

```
public class DraftService : IDraftService
{
IUnitOfWork _uow; <-- if this is disposed and _draft is accessed you'll get an error.
IDbSet<Models.Draft> _draft; <-- might be cached.

public DraftService(IUnitOfWork uow)
{
    _uow = uow; <--- this context is always the same
    _draft = _uow.Set<Models.Draft>();
}

public Models.Draft GetByID(long id)
{
   return _draft.Find(id); <---- this will always use the cached context.
}
}
```

if you make it look like this instead.
you get far less problem.

```
public class DraftService : IDraftService
{
Container _ctn;

public DraftService(Container ctn)
{
    _ctn= ctn;
}

public Models.Draft GetByID(long id)
{
   using(var uow = _ctn.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>()){ // new fresh context. don't forget the AlwaysUnique.
   return uow.Set<Draft>().Find(id); // should return the newer revision.
}}
}
```

if you don't want to passe the container:

```
    public class DraftService : IDraftService
{
IUnitOfWorkResolver _rslv;

public DraftService(IUnitOfWorkResolver rslv)
{
    _rslv= rslv;
}

public Models.Draft GetByID(long id)
{
   using(var uow = rslv.GetContext()){ // new fresh context. don't forget the AlwaysUnique.
   return uow.Set<Draft>().Find(id); // should return the newer revision.
}}
}


public class UnitOfWorkResolver{
   public IUnitOfWork GetContext(){
     return new DBContext(); //or whatever you want you could use Container.Resolve<IUnitOFWork>() instead.
   }
}
```

i didn't put the IUnitOfWorkResolver but you get the idea ...

Comment: It works, but this solution doesn't handle implicit transactions, does it?

Comment: Nope. you would need to scope the transaction in the using statement. or manage the context scope yourself and pass the uow object to the method that will use it, as parameter.

But since you have a DraftService i would expect something like : DraftService.Update(draft draftToUpdate) so the transaction should be scoped to the Update method only.

Comment: I don't want to use the using statement or explicit transaction since I need to handle multiple services operation in one implicit transaction. Imagine that I have a DraftController, in that controller I need to add an instance of Draft and its State to the database in one batch. Thanks to the UnitOfWork it has been handled easily without any explicit transaction. I used this scenario on a web application and it's work fine but in WPF it's not possible because I cannot use "HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()". I think the cache problem is releated to this issue, too. Am I right?

Comment: Try using SingleOrDefault(x => x.id == id) instead of find. Find use the cached entity if it can. 

But you'll still have other problem like context tracking models that shoudn't be tracked and other stuff like that in the long run.

(just realised you where using Find ...)

Comment: I've tried this, but nothing changed. Anyway, thanks for your consideration @Rugdr.

Answer (score 0):

I think the structuremap isn't your problem, you have a problem in Tracking the Entites. Give a look on this article: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/change-tracking-in-entity-framework.aspx

It might be solved by this code:

```
Models.Draft query = _draft.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(r=>r.ID == id);
```

I hope it helps.

Change Tracking in Entity Framework
This section shows how entity framework tracking changes of entities.